# does tf slim fine tuning require gpu?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf-slim

Actually I am trying to fine tune inceptionV3 model using tf slim fine tuning example on git hub it is giving me this error :

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2b_1x1/biases/RMSProp_1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices:
ApplyRMSProp: CPU 
Const: CPU 
Assign: CPU 
IsVariableInitialized: CPU
 
Identity: CPU 
VariableV2: CPU 
     [[Node: InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2b_1x1/biases/RMSProp_1 = VariableV2_class=["loc:@InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2b_1x1/biases"], container="", dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[5], shared_name="", _device="/device:GPU:0"]]

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information about your Tensorflow installation (GPU or CPU installation). If you are running a GPU Tensorflow version this probably is raising the error.

Comment: I have installed CPU version of tensorflow